# complex sequence convergence problem

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis

Let $i=\sqrt{-1}$ and $\{i^{\frac{1}{n}}\}_{n=1}^\infty$ then $i^{\frac{1}{n}}\to 1$ Is the convergence correct?

I've tried $\epsilon>0$ given and Let's take $N=... \in \Bbb{N}$, $n>N$ and $\|i^{\frac{1}
{n}}-1\|<\epsilon$
$$|\|i^{\frac{1}{n}}\|-1|\leq \|i^{\frac{1}
{n}}-1\|<\epsilon$$
$$|\|i\|^{\frac{1}{n}}-1|\leq \|i^{\frac{1}
{n}}-1\|<\epsilon$$  $\|i\|^{\frac{1}{n}}<\epsilon+1$ then $\frac{1}{n}.log\|i\|<log(\epsilon+1)$

we can take $N=\lceil\frac{log\|i\|}{log(\epsilon+1)}\rceil+1$

Do you think i made any mistake?

Comment: $\log||i|| = \log 1 = 0$ so this would mean you can take $N = 1$, which clearly isn't the case since $|i^1 -1|= |i-1| = \sqrt{2}$. I think you would have an easier time letting $i = e^{i\pi(1 + 4k)/2}$ for some integer $k$ and taking the $n^{th}$ root that way

Comment: What is your definition of $z^{1/n}$ ?

Comment: I believe the answer is wrong.  See my answer!

Comment: I asked a question, basically yours, with my analysis.  Seems to have positive acceptance.

Answer (score 0):

4$i=e^{2\pi ki+\frac{\pi i}{2}}$ so $i^\frac{1}{n}=e^{2\pi \frac{k}{n}i+\frac{\pi i}{2n}}$ so for fixed k, $i^\frac{1}{n}\to 1$ as $n\to \infty$.  However $\frac{k}{n}=r$ can be any rational number and a sequence of $mr$ as $m \to \infty$ will approach r.  Therefore there will be a sub-sequence of $i^\frac{1}{n}$ where the the limit is $e^{2\pi ri}$.  Furthermore any real number can be found by a sequence of rationals.

Net result - original assertion is false.

Comment: @Hacemat Note that the revised answer is completely different from original.

Comment: I don’t downvote you (just because I dont want to loose 1 point) but your answer is wrong. $k$ may be unspecified but it must be a constant and its value can not depend on $n$. Just think, why $k$ depends on $n$? If there are another variable $m$, $k$ depends on $m$ as well? it’s non sense.

Comment: Why must k be a constant?  You need to take into account that$i^\frac{1}{n}$ has n equally valid roots and there is is no particular relationship between k(n) and k(m).

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that using the complex logarithm is needed here. It's pretty elementary. The nth roots of $i$ can be written $e^{i\left(\frac{\pi}{2n}+\frac{2 k \pi}{n}\right)}$.

$$  |e^{i\left(\frac{\pi}{2n}+\frac{2 k \pi}{n}\right)}-1|^2=(\cos(\frac{\pi}{2n}+\frac{2 k \pi}{n})-1)^2+\sin(\frac{\pi}{2n}+\frac{2 k \pi}{n})^2$$

Since $\cos(\frac{\pi}{2n}+\frac{2 k \pi}{n}) \to 1 $ and $\sin(\frac{\pi}{2n}+\frac{2 k \pi}{n}) \to 0$, $|e^{i\left(\frac{\pi}{2n}+\frac{2 k \pi}{n}\right)}-1| \to 0$ which shows that $e^{i\left(\frac{\pi}{2n}+\frac{2 k \pi}{n}\right)} \to 1$ (where the limits is defined as the limits for complex sequences).

Comment: You assume that k is fixed as $n\to \infty$.  May not be true!